# Unsuccessful box plot "for" looping with factors in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, boxplot, categorical-data

I have dataset "mydata" with summary of factors `summary(mydata$CLASS)` of

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  A5 
108 236 329 188 175
```

I am attempting to draw five box plots, using the following code:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,2))
for (i in mydata$CLASS) {
  boxplot(mydata$RATIO[which(mydata$CLASS == i)])
}
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

This code produces a number of box plots that far exceeds five; it's in the dozens, at least. Why is this / how do I avoid this?

Comment: Try replacing `(i in mydata$CLASS)` with `(i in unique(mydata$CLASS))`?

Comment: That worked, thanks. Can you write it as an answer so I can officially enter it in?
As an aside, I checked the documentation. Why is the original code producing box plots for duplicates/what are the duplicates that unique() is removing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Z.Lin comments, you are attempting to run `boxplot` on groups of *CLASS* and hence should iterate through its unique values with `unique(mydata$CLASS)`.

Alternatively, consider `tapply` designed to split a vector by factors or *tags* (hence, ***t**agged **apply***) into subsetted groups and run a function across the subsets:

```
par(mfrow = c(3,2))
tapply(mydata$RATIO, mydata$CLASS, FUN=boxplot)
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```

Even consider the object-oriented wrapper to `tapply`: `by` (usually used for splitting dataframes to return a list of objects):

```
par(mfrow = c(3,2))
by(mydata, mydata$CLASS, FUN=function(df) boxplot(df$RATIO))
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
```